# ASP.NET Core 3.1 API referring to a .Net Standard class library - build failed in Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, nuget, .net-standard

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 API which is referring to a .NET Standard 2.1 class library. It's working fine as expected when I run the API from my local machine using Visual Studio (without any errors and warnings).

But when I am deploying using Azure DevOps, the build is failing with the below message:

> Build Steps 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1201: Project ISOXMLValidationLibrary is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project ISOXMLValidationLibrary supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
> NU1201: Project ISOXMLValidationLibrary is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project ISOXMLValidationLibrary supports: netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1)
>
> Errors in
> D:\a\1\s\ISOXMLValidationApi\ISOXMLValidationApi\ISOXMLValidationApi.csproj
> NU1201: Project ISOXMLValidationLibrary is not compatible with
> netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project
> ISOXMLValidationLibrary supports: netstandard2.1
> (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1) Errors in
> D:\a\1\s\ISOXMLValidationApi\ISOXMLValidationApiTest\ISOXMLValidationApiTest.csproj
> NU1201: Project ISOXMLValidationLibrary is not compatible with
> netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project
> ISOXMLValidationLibrary supports: netstandard2.1
> (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1))

Packages failed to restore

Please let me know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was due to old Nuget version. Try changing the Nuget version to a newer one (preferably latest).
You can find the list of versions available in TFS or Azure DevOps server at https://dist.nuget.org/tools.json

Answer (score 1):

In my case, building an old project was ok on my machine but it failed with

> Package IdentityModel 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1).

on the build agent.

Adding a "Use NuGet 5.8.x" step in the (just as old as the project) build definitin solved the issue.